Convexity or quasi-convexity check
Assume $\lambda\geq0$ and $Q$ symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. Consider the function $f(\lambda, Q) = \frac{\lambda\epsilon d}{2}\log(\lambda\epsilon\pi) - \frac{\lambda\epsilon}{2}\log\det(\lambda I-Q)$ with both $\epsilon, d > 0$.
Can I say something about the joint convexity or quasi-convexity of $f$?
What I have tried so far is just simple subcases of the problem where I consider $Q$ a scalar and the identity matrix times a scalar value. In such situation it can be proved joint convexity. But I am stuck when proving or disproving it for the general case.
Can someone provide me with some insights? Thanks!

I might have found the solution.
Consider the matrix function $f(Q) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\log\bigl(\frac{(\epsilon\pi)^d}{det(I-Q)}\bigl)$. This function is convex since $\epsilon$ is positive, $I-Q$ is a linear transformation of $Q$ and $-\log\det(X)$ is convex. Then, the composition of an affine transformation and a convex function is still convex.
If we consider the perspective $g(\lambda, Q) = \lambda f(Q/\lambda)$ we preserve convexity and $g$ is indeed the desired function.
